# Error installing ionic on Mac OS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to install the ionic on but it has error.
I've checked other articles here, but their solution does not help.

I am using the command:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

I am with:

```
$ npm --version
3.10.9
$ node --version
v6.9.2
```

And the error:
[image]

UPDATE:

Answer (score 0):

There are mentions of this on the ionic forums if you do a search [there](https://forum.ionicframework.com/search?q=Enoent%20rename)

What I would so is completely remove ionic and Cordova by running

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
```

And

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Then I would start the process again with

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Just note that this docs say to install Cordova and then Ionic whereas it looks like you did it the other way around which could have caused some issues.